# How can I update my filter function to work generically?

Tags: django, django-models

I overrode the SAVE function in one of my models, and now I want to put it in a MIXIN to be used by other models. But I  have one part I'm not sure how to make generic.

It looks like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(code=code).exists()
```

How can I make reference to 'MyModel' generic so it will work with whatever model imports the override?

Comment: What part(s) need to be generic? The model reference or the filter?

Comment: Good question @Melvyn. I want the model reference to be generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manager is accessed through the class, not the instance. Luckily, python makes that easy:

```py
mgr = self.__class__.objects
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even realize I was asking a Python question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use this in save function all you need is to remove `MyModel` and put `self`

Comment: I don't believe you can use 'self.objects' because at that point, 'self' is an instance of the model.

Comment: it seems i forget to access the class in self like the above answer.